# How can I have "unmet dependency" to the package itself?

Tags: node.js, npm, rxjs, npm-install

I'm running the following.

> PS npm install rxjs --save

The result confuses me beause it says as follows.

> burger-boner@1.0.0 C:\Source\Poc\BurgeBoner
>   `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.3

How can a package be an unmet dependency to itself? What am I missing here?

**edit**

> PS C:\Source\Poc\BurgeBoner> npm list --depth=0
>   burger-boner@1.0.0 C:\Source\Poc\BurgeBoner
>   +-- @angular/common@2.4.4
>   +-- @angular/compiler@2.4.4
>   +-- @angular/core@2.4.4
>   +-- @angular/forms@2.4.4
>   +-- @angular/http@2.4.4
>   +-- @angular/platform-browser@2.4.4
>   +-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.4
>   +-- angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17
>   +-- es6-shim@0.35.2
>   +-- html-webpack-plugin@2.26.0
>   +-- raw-loader@0.5.1
>   +-- reflect-metadata@0.1.9
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.3
>   +-- ts-loader@0.8.2
>   +-- tslint@3.15.1
>   +-- tslint-loader@2.1.5
>   +-- typescript@1.8.10
>   +-- typings@1.5.0
>   +-- webpack@1.14.0
>   +-- webpack-dev-server@1.16.2
>   `-- zone.js@0.7.6

npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4, required by angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17

Comment: What version did npm install?

Comment: Can you provide output of `npm ls` ?

Comment: @lorefnon Please see my edit.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Not sure. How do I verify that? When I entered the directory *node_modules/rxjs*, I can see a bunch of files but no *version.txt* or anything like that. There's a *readme.md* but it doesn't seem to disclose the precise version information neither. It just mentions RXJS5. Then we have *package.json* and in there it seem to mention 5.0.3. Still, please see the edit for what I'm seeing when running `npm install`.

Comment: Are you doing a random `npm install` or are you working with a package.json file already?   It looks like you are trying to install `rxjs@5.0.3`, but `angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17` only wants to work with `rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4`. Maybe try bumping the version of `angular-in-memory-web-api` in your package.json if thats something you have control over.